# Angular: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am working on an angular 6 project with python flask backend. After I deployed Angular frontend, there is a http.post request returning `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error after 1min waiting (the requested API is a bit complex, and it takes about 90s to return).

Here is my code:

```
    const url = this.backend_url + '/api';
    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('p1', 'p1);
    body.set('p2', 'p2');
    return this.http.post(url, body).pipe(timeout(5 * 60 * 1000))
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        response => {
          return response.json();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
```

I guess this problem caused by the default timeout setting of Angular Http Module, as I performed following tests:

1. used Postman to request, it took about 90 seconds and got the response
2. used different browsers for testing, both `Chrome` and `Safari` returned `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` after 1min

Therefore I added `pipe(timeout())` to my code, but it doesn't work. I wonder if there are any people have encountered the same problem or could give any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the API taking a long time to process?

Comment: @Edric Because this API has to complete some cosine similarity computation with some vectors. We are considering to precompute them later. But for the time being, we just want to make it works. XD

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [turn off proxy client (e.g. shasowsocks)](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/183#issuecomment-151543348).

I guess this problem is really really minority. As only a few people would use proxy while testing (e.g. shadowsocks or browser proxy extension).

Still don't know the real reason, but I'd like to answer here for your information.